# How to use hook_menu title arguments

Tags: 7, routes

Reading [hook_menu](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!system!system.api.php/function/hook_menu/7) it says this:

> "title": Required. The untranslated title of the menu item.
>
> "title callback": Function to generate the title; defaults to t(). If you require only the raw string to be output, set this to FALSE.
>
> "title arguments": Arguments to send to t() or your custom callback, with path component substitution as described above.

So how to use it? Right now i have this

```
function custom_gmap_neo_menu(){
    $item = array();

    $item['custom_gmap_neo/%/%/%'] = array( // hotel/origin/destination
        'title' => 'Get directions to @hotel',
        'title arguments' => array(1),
        'page callback' => 'custom_gmap_neo_show',
        'page arguments' => array(1,2,3),
        'access callback' => TRUE,
    );

    return $item;
}

function custom_gmap_neo_show($hotel, $origin, $destination){
    dpm($hotel);
    dpm($origin);
    dpm($destination);

    return '';
}
```

So knowing that default function for title callback is t() how to actually pass the @total wildcard to the t() function?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you define `title arguments` as an array, each array element will be passed as arguments in that sequence.

Now you have `title arguments` defined as `array(1)`, which means the actual call would mimic `t('something')` if the URL path was `custom_gmap_neo/something/something_else/something_else_1`.

If you want to call `t()` function as `t('Get directions to @hotel', array('@hotel' => 'something'))`, you need to define your own `title callback`, because automatic integer to path argument translations only happen in the root level array elements.

```
<?php 
function custom_gmap_neo_menu(){
    $item = array();

    $item['custom_gmap_neo/%/%/%'] = array( // hotel/origin/destination
        'title arguments' => array(1),
        'title callback' => 'custom_gmap_neo_get_map_title'
        'page callback' => 'custom_gmap_neo_show',
        'page arguments' => array(1,2,3),
        'access callback' => TRUE,
    );

    return $item;
}

function custom_gmap_neo_show($hotel, $origin, $destination){
    dpm($hotel);
    dpm($origin);
    dpm($destination);

    return '';
}

function custom_gmap_neo_get_map_title($hotel) {
  return t('Get directions to @hotel', array(
      '@hotel' => $hotel
    ));
}
?>
```

However, if your first URL argument (hotel) is a node, consider using `%node` as the path wildcard, because it can load the node for you, and handles page not found errors automatically if `node_load` returns an empty result. Otherwise you will have to call `node_load` twice. `node_load` caches results, but there are many loader functions that do not cache results.

Comment: hmm i see it clear now, thank you. hotel it is not a node it is just a string